# Export timescale data from MSproject to Excel

Tags: ms-project

I'd like to export timescale data like work to an excel file from MSProject

We are looking to make a custom dashboard in excel but all timescale are not available to export.

It seems like VBA can do it but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual reports automatically exports the OLAP timescaled cube data to Excel and creates a pivot table.  What specifically about the visual reports isn't suiting your needs?